# How to truncate of a real value and discard its non-integer part in awk?

Tags: awk

I have the following dataset (all positive values)

Input file

```
1 2.3456
1 5.02
2 3.9763333
2 0.123
```

I would like to truncate the numbers in the second column and discard its non-integer part.

How would one do it in awk?

Desired output file

```
1 2
1 5
2 3
2 0
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

try the int() function

```
awk '{$2=int($2)}1' file
```

Comment: Note, this does the same as %d in a printf and rounds things down, 3.9763333 will be printed as 3

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{printf("%d %d\n"), $1, $2;}' inputFileName
```

Comment: Note, %d rounds things down, 3.9763333 will be printed as 3

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to truncate rather than round, use `%d` instead of `%0.f`:

```
awk '{printf "%s %d\n", $1, $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do this

```
{ printf "%s %.0f\n", $1, $2}
```

Comment: `%d` is better than `%.0f`, as `%.0f` rounds and `%d` truncates.

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted everyone but for the fun of it here's another one:)

```
awk '{split($2,a,"."); print $1" "a[1]}'
```

Comment: how about : `awk -F"[ \t.]" '{print $1, $2}' file`. no need to create extra array. :)

Comment: @kurumi: Looks good, but what if there's point in the first number? But we can use `$(NF-1)`

Answer (score 0):

If others search for how to floor numbers so that for example -0.1 is converted to -1, you can do something like this:

```
$ printf %s\\n -1 -.9 -.1 0 .1 .9 1|awk '{x=int($0);print(x==$0||$0>0)?x:x-1}'
-1
-1
-1
0
0
0
1
```